# Transform input color in grouped node

Tags: shader-nodes

I can simply make connection as below to transform an Image Texture:
[image]

but if I make a group node with a color input, I found that it is impossible to make transform inside it, because there is no nodes receives a vector and color and output another color:
[image]

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this e.g. like this:

[image]

Just drag whatever input or output you want to that little dark point here:

[image]

which is not connected, so Blender will automatically add that input/output value for you. You can do this with the Group Input and with the Group Output node.